# Sensitivity analysis adding a new variable lpp

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

Some friends and I are having trouble with this sensitivity analysis in a LPP.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nxSJ.jpg

We got the first question right with a python code, but we're having trouble with the second part.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWePe.jpg

This is what we've done so far, but now we're stuck and have no idea what to do since it turns out that the answer was supposed to be c > 8.25

If anyone could help, we would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the 7 in "optimal product 7 mix" is a typo. Second, your calculation of $\bar{c}_8$ if essentially correct, except the initial 7 should be replaced by a variable. (You are solving for the unit contribution of the new product at which including it in the mix would be a break-even proposition.) Third, I don't believe 8.25 is the correct answer.